# JMeter: In search of a meaningful 2-tier architecture

Tags: java, jmeter, architecture, client-server, scalability

For a project, I need to build two client-server-architecture prototypes (2-tier and 3-tier). In a second step I want to test them in terms of performance & scalability with JMeter. In a third step I want to compare the performance of both and give recommendations on the architecture.

I have already built a 3-tier application, which looks like this:

[image: 3-tier]

What I had in mind was to build a 2-tier application, which looks like this:

[image: 2-tier]

But then I realized that I cannot compare them properly. Since there is no possibility to start a function with a HTTP-request in the 2-tier-architecture.

My question now, what would a meaningful implementation of a 2-tier-prototype look like? So that I can make a fair comparison of both.
and if I could use Java that would be great too.

I'm very inexperienced, so I am happy with any input!

Answer (score 1):

In general these 2 implementations look like 2 separate products so comparing their performance is not something you should be doing.

Whatever.

Your "Presentation" statement for the 2-tier architecture doesn't tell the full story:

- if it's some form of a [thin client](https://www.fortinet.com/resources/cyberglossary/thin-client) - then you can use JMeter for simulating load onto "Controller" by impersonating real users, check out [How to Do Desktop Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/desktop-performance-testing) for more details
- if the whole "Client" is a standalone application which just communicates with the database you can:

  - use a [profiler tool](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) to ensure that your "Client" is doing its best in terms of [algorithms efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), absence of [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), etc.
  - the [database can be load tested separately](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) using the aforementioned JMeter
- separate functions or larger code blocks can be tested for concurrency using microbenchmark frameworks like [jmh](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh)

Comment: Alright thanks for your answer, you have brought me a step further.

What about if I build a web application instead of a desktop application:
all the calculations happen in JS, and at the start of the app you get data from the DB.
would it be reasonable to compare both architectures then?

my goal is to compare performance in terms of making calculations on client or server. so i need to get a good comparison scenario.

Comment: Be informed that according to [JMeter Project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/): **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** so if you still considering it for client-side performance testing you will need to go for the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin (can be installed using[JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)). Also "clients" may have different CPU and RAM so you measurement won't make a lot of sense unless you simulate different client hardware somehow

Comment: okay. what would you recommend as a second architecture beside the thin client to create a reasonable scenario? about the application: The business logic (use-cases) are different financial strategies applied to stock data.